# Is there a name for 'distance' between 2 vectors analogous to Chebyshev distance but using min instead of max?

Tags: metric-spaces, terminology

Given two vectors $x$ and $y$, say $x = (0, 0)$ and $y = (3, 4)$,

- Manhattan distance is $3 + 4 = 7$
- Euclidean distance is $\sqrt{3^2 + 4^2} = 5$
- Chebyshev distance is $\max(3, 4) = 4$

Is there a name for the 'distance' $\min(3, 4) = 3$?

What are some applications of this 'distance'?

(I asked this question on stackoverflow and was advised that this might be a better place for it.)

Comment: The minimum is not a metric, so it is not really thought of as a 'distance'.

Comment: That minimum would not represent any actual distance between the two vectors since the maximum would have to be satisfied...

Comment: Given that OP put distance under quotes with min, yet not for the others it is plausible that they are aware that it is not an actual distance. The question if it has a name and if there are applications could be valid regardless it being a distance.

Comment: I think the main application of this "distance" is as an example to be assigned to students to see whether they can prove that it isn't actually a distance.